# HazelcastClientCachingProvider class not found exception when requesting hazelcast jcache provider

Tags: java, caching, hazelcast, jcache

I'm having a strange warning when I try to use Hazelcast-based implementation of JCache (i.e. JSR 107) as follows ([original sample code](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/jcache/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/examples/application/Main.java#L110-L112)):

```
// Explicitly retrieve the Hazelcast backed javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider
CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider(name);
// Retrieve the javax.cache.CacheManager
CacheManager cacheManager = cachingProvider.getCacheManager("com.hazelcast.cache.impl.HazelcastCachingProvider");
```

Here is the logged message:

```
oct. 30, 2014 5:17:59 PM com.hazelcast.cache.impl.HazelcastCachingProvider
WARNING: Could not load client CachingProvider! Fallback to server one... java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.client.cache.impl.HazelcastClientCachingProvider
```

Why it si trying to load `HazelcastClientCachingProvider` will I asked for `com.hazelcast.cache.impl.HazelcastCachingProvider`. Am I using the wrong JCache provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HazelcastCachingProvider is just a delegate to automatically choose either client based or server bases CachingProvider.

For recent 3.4 SNAPSHOTS HazelcastCachingProvider also was moved to `com.hazelcast.cache.HazelcastCachingProvider`. For the new documentation please see the just drafted documentation version for 3.4: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-documentation/src/JCache.md

You'll see it got waaaaaaay longer :)

Comment: so I don't have to worry for the warning?

Comment: Nope, just ignore it :)